# Keras custom accuracy function incompatible shapes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to use the following custom accuracy function in my model:

```
def acc_fn(pred, gt):
    pred_occupy = pred[..., 1] >= config.IOU_THRESHOLD
    I1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.math.logical_and(pred_occupy, tf.cast(gt, tf.bool)), tf.float32))
    I2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.math.logical_or(pred_occupy, tf.cast(gt, tf.bool)), tf.float32))
    IoU = tf.math.divide(I1, I2, name = "IoU")
    tf.summary.scalar("IoU", IoU)
    return IoU
```

invoked in keras like:

```
model.compile(loss=loss_fn, #categorical crossentropy
                optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=config.LR),
                metrics=[acc_fn])
```

I am getting incompatible shapes error while fitting the model:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [1,128,128,128,2] vs. [1,128,128,128]
```

My model outputs a hot encoded layer of shape `[1,128,128,128,2]` and the ground truth array is hot-encoded as well and of the same shape!

the last couple of layers in my model

```
add_10 (Add)                    (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv3d_11[0][0]
                                                                 conv3d_13[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_14 (Conv3D)              (None, 128, 128, 128 433         add_10[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv3d_14[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 128, 128 0           conv3d_14[0][0]
                                                                 lambda_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax_1 (Softmax)             (None, 128, 128, 128 0           concatenate_1[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 176,458,081
Trainable params: 176,451,105
Non-trainable params: 6,976
```

Comment: did u try pred_occupy = tf.expand_dim(pred_occupy, -1) before I1 and I2 ?

Comment: how would that help? `tf.expand_dim` add single axis only

Comment: pred_occupy is 4D while gt is 5D... how could you compare them? u need pred_occupy to be 5D, for that reason, u can use expand_dim